# Search and replace uppercase letters with lowercase letters

Tags: substitute

I have bunch of strings that starts with uppercase letters. I want to change uppercase letters with lowercase letters. Strings are not aligned so visual block mode is not an option. Is it possible to use `substitute` to do this?

Before:

```
'Readable & writeable outside of effects'
'Multiple signal reads in same effect should only register once'
```

After:

```
'readable & writeable outside of effects'
'multiple signal reads in same effect should only register once'
```

Comment: In your example the letter to substitute is always the first of the line (contradicting the statement about their position). Maybe could you give us a better example to tune the proposed substitution expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `\l` or the ´\L´ operator in the substitution:

e.g.:

```
:%s/^\w\+/\l&/
```

will substitute the first letter of the first words of each line to its lowercase version.

```
:%s/'\(\_[^']*\)'/'\l\1'/g
```

will substitute the first letter of a quoted string to its lowercase version

Comment: `:%s/'\u/\L&` got the job done. `\u` matches uppercase letters

Comment: @s1n7ax why is it `L` and not the lowercase `l`?

Comment: @s1n7ax what does the `&` do?

Comment: It is equivalent to `\0`. It stand for the matching string.

Comment: to replace KamelCase part, without quotes: `%s/\([A-Z]\)/\l\1/cg`

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with the `gu` command and a motion: `ggguG`. To make everything uppercase, use: `gggUG`. Explanation (with mnemonic devices):

1. `gg` go to the first row.
2. `gu` go lowercase from here...
3. `G` to the end of the file.